# I keep getting a "TypeError: undefined is not an object" error message

Tags: javascript, promise, typeerror

I've been trying to make a script to let users install a configuration profile on their iOS or iPadOS devices, and my code is:

```
function downloadProfile(profileName, configurationProfile) {
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("href", "data:application/x-apple-aspen-config," + encodeURIComponent(configurationProfile));
    element.setAttribute("download", profileName + ".mobileconfig");

    element.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    element.body.removeChild();
}
```

The problem is, I keep getting an error message saying `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'element.body.appendChild')`. Does anyone know a fix? This is not the entire code of course, it's just the part that I need help with.

Comment: replace `element.body.appendChild` with `document.body.appendChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you create does not have a property body. I assume you want to add the new element to the document, like so instead:

```
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Check you for an example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp